# In C# isn't explicit casting of an interface to another, type checked?

Tags: c#, interface

I was surprised to find out I can do this:

```
// code snipped from C# interactive
public interface I1 { }
public interface I2 { }
I1 i1;
I2 i2 = (I2)i1 // explicit cast to an arbitrary type, works!
```

Why is this allowed?

I thought the behavior of interfaces in the above scenario will be same as with classes, like:

```
// code snipped from C# interactive
public class C1 { }
public class C2 { }
C1 c1;
C2 c2 = (C2)c1; //error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'C1' to 'C2'
```

Comment: Rationale as I understand it is: It's possible that some instance implementing `I1` could also implement `I2`. But a class C1 that is not explicitly marked as inheriting C2, doesn't, by definition, inherit C2. (note that, as all features of any language, it is ultimately a design/implementation choice). EDIT: was looking for the Eric Lippert's quotation, eventually it was given faster in the answer below.

Comment: Eric Lippert's quote's from the answer captured the essence of the reasoning for me.. sadly now removed :(  ...inline with what @Pac0 says, the language choice! good to know though..

Comment: @SocialDeveloper I realized Lippert's quote did not actually answer the specifics of the question, hence deleting my answer. I have updated my answer to answer the question that you are specifically asking

Comment: For anyone looking for the quote I deleted: [Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366601/402462)

Comment: @SocialDeveloper please do not forget to select an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: there is no case in which `C1` can be casted to `C2` (and the compiler knows this because you have explicitly defined `C1` and `C2` to inherit from no type other than `object`), but there are many cases in which something that implements `I1` might also implement `I2`.

For example:

```
    public interface I1 { }
    public interface I2 { }

    public class C1: I2, I1 { }


    public void Method()
    {
        I1 implementor = new C1();
        I2 implementor2 = (I2)implementor;//totally safe at both compile time and run time
    }
```

Here `C1` implements `I1` as well as `I2`, so a cast to `I2` is valid. All the compiler knows is that `implementor` is some class that implements `I1`. Could there be some class that implements `I1` that also implements `I2`? Of course, we can use `C1` as an example. The complier will let it slide and the error will occur at runtime if the concrete class does not implement `I2`.

That being said, I would absolutely not recommend casting some interface to another interface willy-nilly.

Comment: If you wish to close the question, I guess it would me more customary on Stack Overflow to write this as a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @Pac0 yes, but I also provided an answer. I removed the part about voting to close